# IE 11 unloading window on HTML select selection

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

While pages unload and load, I wanted to hiade a little the display and show a gif images searching.

in my body page :

```
<div id="loading">
    <img id="loading-image" src="{{ asset('bundles/accueil/images/ajax-loader.gif') }}" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

in js:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
};

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
};
```

in css:

```
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  -moz-opacity: 0.70;
  opacity:.70;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
```

}

It works good with Firefox and Chrome.

With IE 11 I have some problems :

1. The gif image does not move (seems to be a IE Bug).
2. But the most disturbing thing is that when I open a select HTML Element, my gif image appears like the page has been unloaded.

Comment: Do you have a submit or other handler bound to the select?

Comment: No.. I dont have anything linked to this select

Comment: I've also had problems trying to display a div in the onbeforeunload function in IE11. I forget if it didn't appear or it froze the screen... In the end I opened a new window instead with a message file which paused for N seconds after loading then auto-closed.